# How to check elements from an array in a CheckListBox

Tags: vb.net, checklistbox

i have a checklisbox with some value, let's say
"Apple"
"Peach"
"Lemon"
These values came from a dataset.

I have an array with Apple and Lemon: {"Apple", "Lemon"}.
How to check in the checklistbox each value read in this array?

EDIT: In my case, the checklistbox was populate using a dataset provided by a SQL query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following code sample, data from SQL-Server (database doesn't matter but this is what I used, what is important is the container the data is loaded into is loaded into a list.

[image]

**Container to hold data**

```
Public Class Category
    Public Property Id() As Integer
    Public Property Name() As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function
End Class
```

**Class to read data**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class SqlOperations
    Private Shared ConnectionString As String =
                "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NorthWind2020;Integrated Security=True"

    Public Shared Function Categories() As List(Of Category)
        Dim categoriesList = New List(Of Category)
        Dim selectStatement = "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories;"

        Using cn As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = ConnectionString}
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand With {.Connection = cn}

                cmd.CommandText = selectStatement

                cn.Open()

                Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                    categoriesList.Add(New Category() With {.Id = reader.GetInt32(0), .Name = reader.GetString(1)})
                End While


            End Using

        End Using

        Return categoriesList

    End Function

End Class
```

**Extension method**

Which can check or uncheck a value if found in the CheckedListBox and is case insensitive.

```
Public Module Extensions
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Function SetCategory(sender As CheckedListBox, text As String, Optional checkedValue As Boolean = True) As Boolean

        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) Then
            Return False
        End If

        Dim result = CType(sender.DataSource, List(Of Category)).
                Select(Function(item, index) New With
                          {
                            Key .Column = item,
                            Key .Index = index
                          }).FirstOrDefault(Function(this) _
                             String.Equals(this.Column.Name, text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))

        If result IsNot Nothing Then
            sender.SetItemChecked(result.Index, checkedValue)
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

End Module
```

**Form code**

```
Public Class ExampleForm
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        CheckedListBox1.DataSource = SqlOperations.Categories
    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckCategoryButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckCategoryButton.Click
        CheckedListBox1.SetCategory(CategoryToCheckTextBox.Text, StateCheckBox.Checked)
    End Sub
End Class
```

To **check all** at once

```
Private Sub CheckAllButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckAllButton.Click
    CType(CheckedListBox1.DataSource, List(Of Category)).
        ForEach(Sub(cat) CheckedListBox1.SetCategory(cat.Name, True))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Karen for this very detailed answer, it works! 
By the way, i don't figure out why it's genuinely complicated to deal with checklist box

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned exactly how the `CheckedListBox` gets populated by the `DataSet`, I've made the assumption that you add Strings directly to the Items collection.

This code will simply loop through the CheckedListBox and compare the values with the array, whatever the match result, the Checkbox is either ticked or cleared.

```
    Dim theArray() As String = {"Apple", "Lemon"}

    For counter As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1

        Dim currentItem As String = CheckedListBox1.Items(counter).ToString

        Dim match As Boolean = theArray.Contains(currentItem.ToString)

        CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(counter, match)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SetItemChecked` method like this:

```
CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(CheckedListBox1.Items.IndexOf("your item goes here"), True)
```

Note that if the item does not exist, an exception will be thrown, so be sure to check for the item before calling the `SetItemChecked()` method. To do that, you can check for the return value of `IndexOf()`. It will be -1 if the item does not exist.